# Connect Android Studio to Team Foundation Version Control

Tags: android-studio, azure-devops, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm trying to connect my Android Studio IDE with the Visual Studio Online (TFS), where all my other `.net` connected to using Visual Studio (.net developers) in order to be able to check in files to the same repository.
I've installed the latest Visual Studio (2.2) and TF Command line tool and followed by the instruction here...
[enter link description here](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-setup-requirements)

Anyway, once I open up Android Studio, go to "check out project from source control" I choose "Team Service TFVC (Preview)". and I'm able to see my repository. but when I press "create Workspace", I get the below error message

> Plugin Error - visual studio team service threw an uncaught exception
>   RunTimeException.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce this issue too. You can submit the feedback by clicking feedback button (beside create workspace) or as David said that you can send the email to leantk@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this.  Can you please contact "leantk at microsoft dt com" so that we can help troubleshoot and fix the problem?  We'll then post the results back here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi David, i found leantk at microsoft forum but didn't know how to contact him directly, so I've posted the same question here, i hope it is ok.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/739fecc3-b062-46f0-adb9-a39edc119aac/connect-android-studio-to-team-foundation-version-control?forum=tee

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
When you try to create a new workspace and get Plugin Error, you need to change the "Directory Name" to a name the has not been used before.
Microsoft will fix it in the next release.
Good luck!